# ExitCode not returned on CMD

Tags: c#, wpf, batch-file, cmd, exit-code

I am currently working on a WPF Application which is providing `ExitCode`s to be found in the `Windows Eventlog`.

In some cases I need to cancel execution immediatly.
Therefore I use `Environment.Exit(someInteger)`.
There also is the need to start it via batch and check if the `ErrorLevel is NOT 0`.

---

**Output via VisualStudio OutputConsole:**

```
 The program '[6908] MyApp.vshost.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
 The program '[6908] MyApp.vshost.exe' has exited with code 3 (0x3).
```

**CMD Output:**

```
cd MyVisualStudioDebugDir
MyApp.exe
echo %errorlevel% 
=> returns 0
```

---

**Why am I getting 0 here when I call** `Environment.Exit(3)` **?**

Comment: Are you sure that previous lines in your example are _not_ placed inside parentheses? In such a case, you need to enable delayed expansion and use `echo !errorlevel!` instead.

Comment: "Program trace" is a helper process that feeds the VS2015 diagnostic tools.  It collects the ETW events from your real program so that VS can show you the cpu and memory usage statistics.  Nothing wrong with it of course, seeing it exit with code 0 is normal.  The way you are using %errorlevel% can only work for console mode apps.  A WPF app gets started without cmd.exe waiting for it to complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure but it could be related to how you might be invoking the EXE in your script. To mimic your situation, I created a simple WPF application that immediately exits via `Environment.Exit(3);` and then a simple `test.cmd` script:

```
@echo off

start /wait TestApp.exe
echo %ERRORLEVEL%
```

What was echoed was in fact `3`.

**Update:** I noticed that the ERRORLEVEL is not properly set if `start` is used without the `/wait` option. I believe this is due to the fact that `start` will not wait for the application to exit before continuing. Therefore you can use `start /wait TestApp.exe` or simply `call TestApp.exe`. I have updated the example above.

Comment: I am currently calling .Exit() in the constructor of my MainClass and starting the exe from my VS Debug direcotry. For me it is not working :( what am I missing

Comment: I updated the answer. I believe `start` cannot be used without the `/wait` option (or simply use `call`).

Comment: That was the problem :D I don't really get why but it's solved. Thanks a lot

Comment: My gut leans towards a possible race condition. If the script checks the ERRORLEVEL value before the application exits, then you won't see the updated error code. The `/wait` option or use of `call` keeps the script from continuing before the application does in fact exit.

Comment: KK got it now :D. Tanks !

Comment: If you use `start /wait MyApp.exe` the result is the same than just `MyApp.exe`. The original question does _not_ mentioned any `start` command...

Comment: @Aacini No, it's not the same, as `start /wait` will wait even for a non console app. `calc.exe` will start and immediatly return, but `start /wait calc.exe` waits until you close calc

Answer (score 0):

> On the command line, CMD.EXE does not wait for the application to
>   terminate and control immediately returns to the command prompt.
>
> Within a command script CMD.EXE will pause the initial script and wait
>   for the application to terminate before continuing.

[Description about cmd and exit codes](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html)

So put your application launching command to a batch file and run that batch file in cmd.

**myBat.bat**

```
MyApp.exe
echo %errorlevel%
```

Error level will be correct.